# Median of two sorted arrays of equal length

Tags: algorithm, array-algorithms

I have been trying to understand why the following algorithm works to no avail.

```
1) Calculate the medians m1 and m2 of the input arrays ar1[] 
   and ar2[] respectively.
2) If m1 and m2 both are equal then we are done.
     return m1 (or m2)
3) If m1 is greater than m2, then median is present in one 
   of the below two subarrays.
    a)  From first element of ar1 to m1 (ar1[0...|_n/2_|])
    b)  From m2 to last element of ar2  (ar2[|_n/2_|...n-1])
4) If m2 is greater than m1, then median is present in one    
   of the below two subarrays.
   a)  From m1 to last element of ar1  (ar1[|_n/2_|...n-1])
   b)  From first element of ar2 to m2 (ar2[0...|_n/2_|])
5) Repeat the above process until size of both the subarrays 
   becomes 2.
6) If size of the two arrays is 2 then use below formula to get 
  the median.
    Median = (max(ar1[0], ar2[0]) + min(ar1[1], ar2[1]))/2
```

My diffculty is in the steps 3 and 4 which are the core of the algorithm. Here is my thinking:

If m1 > m2 then m1 is greater than half of the elements in the merged array, so why would we want to explore ar1[0...|*n/2*|]?

Comment: If m1 is too big and m2 is too small, then the actual median can't be in ar1 above m1 or in ar2 below m2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following example. It demonstrates the case you're asking about.

```
ar1[] = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
ar2[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

> If m1 > m2 then m1 is greater than half of the elements in the merged array, so why would we want to explore ar1[0...|n/2|]?

The key to understanding this algorithm is to look at what you're eliminating at each step, not just what you're keeping. It's true that since `m1 > m2`, we know that `m1` is greater than half the elements in the merged array. It doesn't tell us where in relation to the merged median `m1` is though. All we really know about the relation between `ar1` and the merged median is that we can eliminate everything greater than `m1` (and less than `m2` from `ar2`).  The median of the merged list is somewhere in what remains.

```
ar1[] = {6, 7, 8}
ar2[] = {3, 4, 5}
```

Answer (score 3):

We know that m1 is larger than or equal to the first half of ar1. And the same for m2 and ar2. At the same time we also know that m1 is smaller than or equal to the second half of ar1.

Let's consider the case m1 > m2

```
ar1:     [.....m1.....]
ar2:     [.....m2.....]
ar1+ar2: [.....m2..m1........]
```

Let us call the median of the merged array m*. Since the first halves of ar1 and ar2 come before m1. We have that m1 => m*, this means that no values larger than m1 need to be considered in ar1. So we only need to look in the first half or ar1.

Similarly, since the second halves of ar1 and ar2 come after m1, we have that m2 <= m*, this means that no values smaller than m2 need to be considered and we only need to look in the second half of ar2.

This is exactly what steps 3 and 4 do.